# Proposed update to Help Center for "Identify-This-X Questions"

Tags: discussion

Currently, the help center reads like this:

> Identify-This-X Questions
>
> Identification questions are currently on-topic for this site **with the
>   exception of commercials, music videos and questions consisting only
>   of an image for detail**. Please try to show effort and give as much
>   detail as possible:

I think this is a bit confusing and not entirely true to the state of the site.  The ID questions that are truly on-topic are:

- movies
- tv shows
- tv show episodes
- actors

I propose that we update the text to something like:

> Identification questions are currently on-topic for this site in
>   regards to identifying **actors, movies, tv shows, and specific episodes of tv
>   shows**.  ID questions must be as descriptive as possible and cannot consist
>   of only an image.  Important details to include are:

Also, the current wording for closing as Off-Topic: Identification reads as:

> **Identification** questions must contain sufficient detail to meet the
>   site's quality standards and should not be about a commercial, music
>   video or consist only of an image. For help writing a good
>   identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

I think we should reword this to something like:

> **Identification** questions must contain sufficient detail to meet the
>   site's quality standards. They should be about identifying an actor,
>   movie, TV show, or a specific episode of a TV show and should not
>   consist only of an image. For help writing a good identification
>   question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

I'm open to tweaking the wording, but I think as it stands the Help Center doesn't quite reflect reality.

Comment: I agree with it being more positive to look at this from a "what **can** I ask" viewpoint... I believe this text is also used for the close reason. Do you suggest changing this, too?

Comment: @Catija yes, the wording on the Off-Topic : Identification description should also be updated

Comment: @Catija I have updated my question

Comment: That's a complex sentence... Perhaps: *Identification questions must contain sufficient detail to meet the site's quality standards. They should be about identifying an actor, movie, TV show, or a specific episode of a TV show and should not consist only of an image. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.* ?

Comment: @Catija that's better.  I've updated the wording

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a reasonable change broadly endorsed by the community. It has thus been put in place for the help center as well as the close reason.

Comment: YAY!! Finally a less confusing close reason.